# Image positioning in Listview search

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the pictures when I use the search then the app always takes the first picture instead of the picture that belongs.
I added two pictures where you can see what I mean by "`Adrenaline`".
Can someone help me by chance?
I would be very happy.

Sorry for my bad English.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owESV.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx8ne.png)

````
package com.0000.00000;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.animation.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class PerksActivity extends Activity {


    private HashMap<String, Object> map_var = new HashMap<>();
    private String saved = "";
    private double length = 0;
    private double r = 0;
    private String value1 = "";
    private String value2 = "";
    private String value3 = "";
    private String value4 = "";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map_list = new ArrayList<>();

    private LinearLayout linear1;
    private LinearLayout linear2;
    private LinearLayout linear3;
    private LinearLayout linear10;
    private LinearLayout linear11;
    private LinearLayout linear12;
    private TextView textview4;
    private AdView adview1;
    private LinearLayout linear15;
    private LinearLayout linear16;
    private LinearLayout linear44;
    private ListView listview1;
    private EditText edittext1;
    private LinearLayout linear929;
    private TextView textview8;

    private InterstitialAd admob;
    private AdListener _admob_ad_listener;
    private Intent page_intent = new Intent();
    private AlertDialog.Builder popup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.perks);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState);
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {

        linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);
        linear10 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear10);
        linear11 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear11);
        linear12 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear12);
        textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
        adview1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adview1);
        linear15 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear15);
        linear16 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear16);
        linear44 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear44);
        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        linear929 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear929);
        textview8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview8);
        popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _param1, View _param2, int _param3, long _param4) {
                final int _position = _param3;
                if (_position == 0) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                if (_position == 1) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                if (_position == 2) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                        }
        });

        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence _param1, int _param2, int _param3, int _param4) {
                final String _charSeq = _param1.toString();
                map_list = new Gson().fromJson(saved, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
                length = map_list.size();
                r = length - 1;
                for(int _repeat17 = 0; _repeat17 < (int)(length); _repeat17++) {
                    value1 = map_list.get((int)r).get("a").toString();
                    value2 = map_list.get((int)r).get("b").toString();
                    value3 = map_list.get((int)r).get("c").toString();
                    if (!(_charSeq.length() > value1.length()) && value1.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                    }
                    else {
                        if (!(_charSeq.length() > value2.length()) && value2.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                        }
                        else {
                            if (!(_charSeq.length() > value3.length()) && value3.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                            }
                            else {
                                map_list.remove((int)(r));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    r--;
                }
                listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(map_list));
                ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence _param1, int _param2, int _param3, int _param4) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable _param1) {

            }
        });

        _admob_ad_listener = new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                admob.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int _param1) {
                final int _errorCode = _param1;
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Werbung konnte nicht Geladen werden!!!".concat(String.valueOf((long)(_errorCode))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

            }
        };
    }
    private void initializeLogic() {
        adview1.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("0815")
                .build());
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perksstriche));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebende));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perksstriche02));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perksinfopopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perksinfopopuptxtname));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungname));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendenadamfrancisname));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perkslehrbarimblutnetzlevel30name));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungpopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungpopuptxt));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinname));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendenmegthomasname));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perkslehrbarimblutnetzlevel40name));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinpopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinpopuptxt));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        
        listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(map_list));
        ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        saved = new Gson().toJson(map_list);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.perk_ueberlebende);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.adam_francis_perk_ablenkung);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.meg_thomas_perk_adrenalin);

    }

    private ArrayList<Integer>
            image_list = new ArrayList<>();
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);

        switch (_requestCode) {

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public class Listview1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;
        public Listview1Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr) {
            _data = _arr;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int _index) {
            return _data.get(_index);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int _index) {
            return _index;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int _position, View _view, ViewGroup _viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View _v = _view;
            if (_v == null) {
                _v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.perkssearch, null);
            }

            final LinearLayout linear1 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
            final ImageView imageview1 = (ImageView) _v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
            final LinearLayout linear2 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear2);
            final LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
            final TextView textview1 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            final TextView textview2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            final TextView textview3 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

            textview1.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("a").toString());
            textview2.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("b").toString());
            textview3.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("c").toString());
            imageview1.setImageResource
                    (image_list.get(_position));
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebende)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksvonkeinezuordnungname)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendendwightfairfieldname)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFF8BC34A);
            }

            return _v;
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void showMessage(String _s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationX(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[0];
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationY(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[1];
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getRandom(int _min, int _max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(_max - _min + 1) + _min;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public ArrayList<Double> getCheckedItemPositionsToArray(ListView _list) {
        ArrayList<Double> _result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        SparseBooleanArray _arr = _list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int _iIdx = 0; _iIdx < _arr.size(); _iIdx++) {
            if (_arr.valueAt(_iIdx))
                _result.add((double)_arr.keyAt(_iIdx));
        }
        return _result;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public float getDip(int _input){
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, _input, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayWidthPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayHeightPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }

} ```
````

Comment: please add your images into the question, because the external links could become invalid in the futur.

Answer (score 1):

Transfer this statement to the top

```java
public class PerksActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Integer> image_list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

I see you have maintained your integer type casting but missed it when setting image resource in `getview`.

`imageview1.setImageResource(image_list.get((int)_position))`

Hope it works

Comment: Someone has a solution? :(

Answer (score 1):

Nothing has changed.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.animation.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class PerksActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Integer> image_list = new ArrayList<>();


    private HashMap<String, Object> map_var = new HashMap<>();
    private String saved = "";
    private double length = 0;
    private double r = 0;
    private String value1 = "";
    private String value2 = "";
    private String value3 = "";
    private String value4 = "";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> map_list = new ArrayList<>();

    private LinearLayout linear1;
    private LinearLayout linear2;
    private LinearLayout linear3;
    private LinearLayout linear10;
    private LinearLayout linear11;
    private LinearLayout linear12;
    private TextView textview4;
    private AdView adview1;
    private LinearLayout linear15;
    private LinearLayout linear16;
    private LinearLayout linear44;
    private ListView listview1;
    private EditText edittext1;
    private LinearLayout linear929;
    private TextView textview8;

    private InterstitialAd admob;
    private AdListener _admob_ad_listener;
    private Intent page_intent = new Intent();
    private AlertDialog.Builder popup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(_savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.perks);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState);
        initializeLogic();
    }

    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState) {

        linear1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        linear2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear2);
        linear3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear3);
        linear10 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear10);
        linear11 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear11);
        linear12 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear12);
        textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview4);
        adview1 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adview1);
        linear15 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear15);
        linear16 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear16);
        linear44 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear44);
        listview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        linear929 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear929);
        textview8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview8);
        popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        listview1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> _param1, View _param2, int _param3, long _param4) {
                final int _position = _param3;
                if (_position == 0) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                if (_position == 1) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                if (_position == 2) {
                    popup.setTitle(map_list.get((int)_position).get("d").toString());
                    popup.setMessage(map_list.get((int)_position).get("e").toString());
                    popup.setPositiveButton("Schliessen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface _dialog, int _which) {

                        }
                    });
                    popup.create().show();
                }
                        }
        });

        edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence _param1, int _param2, int _param3, int _param4) {
                final String _charSeq = _param1.toString();
                map_list = new Gson().fromJson(saved, new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){}.getType());
                length = map_list.size();
                r = length - 1;
                for(int _repeat17 = 0; _repeat17 < (int)(length); _repeat17++) {
                    value1 = map_list.get((int)r).get("a").toString();
                    value2 = map_list.get((int)r).get("b").toString();
                    value3 = map_list.get((int)r).get("c").toString();
                    if (!(_charSeq.length() > value1.length()) && value1.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                    }
                    else {
                        if (!(_charSeq.length() > value2.length()) && value2.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                        }
                        else {
                            if (!(_charSeq.length() > value3.length()) && value3.toLowerCase().contains(_charSeq.toLowerCase())) {

                            }
                            else {
                                map_list.remove((int)(r));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    r--;
                }
                listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(map_list));
                ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence _param1, int _param2, int _param3, int _param4) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable _param1) {

            }
        });

        _admob_ad_listener = new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                admob.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int _param1) {
                final int _errorCode = _param1;
                SketchwareUtil.showMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Werbung konnte nicht Geladen werden!!!".concat(String.valueOf((long)(_errorCode))));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {

            }
        };
    }
    private void initializeLogic() {
        adview1.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("0815")
                .build());
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perksstriche));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebende));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perksstriche02));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perksinfopopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perksinfopopuptxtname));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungname));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendenadamfrancisname));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perkslehrbarimblutnetzlevel30name));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungpopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perkablenkungpopuptxt));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        map_var = new HashMap<>();
        map_var.put("a", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinname));
        map_var.put("b", getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendenmegthomasname));
        map_var.put("c", getResources().getString(R.string.perkslehrbarimblutnetzlevel40name));
        map_var.put("d", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinpopupheadername));
        map_var.put("e", getResources().getString(R.string.perkadrenalinpopuptxt));
        map_list.add(map_var);
        
        listview1.setAdapter(new Listview1Adapter(map_list));
        ((BaseAdapter)listview1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        saved = new Gson().toJson(map_list);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.perk_ueberlebende);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.adam_francis_perk_ablenkung);
        image_list.add(R.drawable.meg_thomas_perk_adrenalin);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int _requestCode, int _resultCode, Intent _data) {
        super.onActivityResult(_requestCode, _resultCode, _data);

        switch (_requestCode) {

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public class Listview1Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;
        public Listview1Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr) {
            _data = _arr;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return _data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int _index) {
            return _data.get(_index);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int _index) {
            return _index;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int _position, View _view, ViewGroup _viewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View _v = _view;
            if (_v == null) {
                _v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.perkssearch, null);
            }

            final LinearLayout linear1 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
            final ImageView imageview1 = (ImageView) _v.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
            final LinearLayout linear2 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear2);
            final LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
            final TextView textview1 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
            final TextView textview2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
            final TextView textview3 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

            textview1.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("a").toString());
            textview2.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("b").toString());
            textview3.setText(map_list.get((int)_position).get("c").toString());
            imageview1.setImageResource(image_list.get((int)_position));
            
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebende)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksvonkeinezuordnungname)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
            if (textview2.getText().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.perksueberlebendendwightfairfieldname)) ) {
                textview2.setTextColor(0xFF8BC34A);
            }

            return _v;
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void showMessage(String _s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), _s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationX(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[0];
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getLocationY(View _v) {
        int _location[] = new int[2];
        _v.getLocationInWindow(_location);
        return _location[1];
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getRandom(int _min, int _max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(_max - _min + 1) + _min;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public ArrayList<Double> getCheckedItemPositionsToArray(ListView _list) {
        ArrayList<Double> _result = new ArrayList<Double>();
        SparseBooleanArray _arr = _list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int _iIdx = 0; _iIdx < _arr.size(); _iIdx++) {
            if (_arr.valueAt(_iIdx))
                _result.add((double)_arr.keyAt(_iIdx));
        }
        return _result;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public float getDip(int _input){
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, _input, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayWidthPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    @Deprecated
    public int getDisplayHeightPixels(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }

}
```